# What does this symbol that looks like two disconnected points joined by a curved line mean?

Tags: identification, schematics, symbol

What does this schematics symbol mean?

[image: Unidentified symbol]

Taken from [here](http://site.gravitech.us/MicroResearch/I2C/I2C-PROX/SCH-I2C-PROX.pdf).
I got the PCB and it's not a button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a solder bridge. Sometimes there can be a jumper that you need to put, sometimes it is just two very close pads that you join with a blob of solder.

[image: Solder bridge jumper]

Comment: Looking at this [picture](http://site.gravitech.us/MicroResearch/I2C/I2C-PROX/I2C-PROX_3.jpg) of the I2C-PROX board that the [schematic](http://site.gravitech.us/MicroResearch/I2C/I2C-PROX/SCH-I2C-PROX.pdf) in the question points to you are definitely right.

Answer (score 4):

Either a jumper or a cuttable trace on the pcb (as opposed to a unpopulated trace). As an i2c module, it's so you can disconnect the on board i2c pullups if you have them somewhere else or if the values don't suit your need. A picture of the board would confirm, but I'm 110% on this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jumper; The LED ON/OFF we configure through the this jumper.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Probably grammar. He is right that the led is also using a solder jumper here, I only saw the i2c pullups.